# What is the difference between Python's pyautogui.PAUSE and time.sleep?

Tags: python, time, pyautogui

I've noticed that pyautogui.PAUSE makes my program run slightly slower. I'm wondering why this is?

Answer (score 3):

From the [source code](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=PAUSE&type=):

```
PAUSE = 0.1 # The number of seconds to pause after EVERY public function call. Useful for debugging.
```

So essentially, each function is slowed down by 0.1 seconds, hence the slowdown.

Answer (score 1):

The method sleep() suspends execution for the given number of seconds.
Example:

```
time.sleep(5)
```

the execution will be suspended for 5 seconds.

In the case of `pyautogui.PAUSE` allows you to add delays after PyAutoGUI’s functions. 
For more information you could read: 
[sleep](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_sleep.htm) and 
[pause](http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cheatsheet.html)

So, both functions add pause, that may be the reason for slowness.
I hope this help you.